# Mouseover event don't work (vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to make a battleship game and I have a problem with `mouseover` event in Javascript. I want to make a function that will change element's text content to "X" when is mouse over this element.

Javascript:

```
var gridShips = document.querySelectorAll('.ships');

for(var i=0; i++; i<gridShips.length){
    gridShips[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){placeShips(e)}, false);
}
function placeShips(e){
e.target.textContent = 'X';

}
```

But when I get my mouse over this element nothing changes. Only when I click on this element, the text content is changing to 'X'. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your for-loop is incorrect. The middle section is the one that gets checked to be true/false, and the last section is run every iteration (sections as in what's separated by the semicolons).

Try changing it from `for(var i=0; i++; i<gridShips.length)`
to `for(var i=0; i<gridShips.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead since you do not need the index.

```
for(const ship of gridShips){
    ship.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){placeShips(e)}, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the standard for loop in javascript is:

for ( initializer ; stop condition ; increment amount ) { ... }

such as

for ( let i = 0; i < gridShips.length; i++ ) { ... }

however, maybe i am misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish, but I would think you want to listen for the click event. as Players need to select a tile to attack in battle ship during their turn.  otherwise you would use up your turn the moment you move the mouse onto the board, it would attack what ever square you mouse over first.